# knitr markdown removes image file from project folder

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have this basic R markdown file:

```
---
title: 'test'
output:
  html_document
---

![myimage](test.png)
```

The file `test.png` can be found in the project folder. If I compile the document the first time all is good:

```
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS /Users/nf/test/test_file.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output test_file.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/x0/87l48swx73lg569_81cctqt00000gp/T//RtmpYYJgwp/rmarkdown-stree426f43954e.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight 


processing file: test_file.Rmd
output file: /Users/nf/test/test_file.knit.md


Output created: test_file.html
```

But if I compile it the second time (without changing anything) I get this error:

```
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code




processing file: test_file.Rmd
output file: /Users/nf/test/test_file.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS /Users/nf/test/test_file.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output test_file.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/x0/87l48swx73lg569_81cctqt00000gp/T//RtmprFBDzb/rmarkdown-streef56b8e7e99.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight 
pandoc: Could not fetch test.png
test.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

If I look into my project folder the image `test.png` is gone. In the process of the first compilation of the document the image get's deleted. I can reproduce it every time. And then of course it is missing for the second compilation. This also happens with `.RData` files I load inside R chunks. I even tried to keep the files in a separate folder and copy them every time inside my project folder I compile my document (with the command `file.copy()`). But then the files in the outside folder disappear as well. It seems that every file mentioned in the markdown document gets deleted or moved somewhere else.

What I found out is that this happens only if the name of the markdown file contains spaces like `test file.Rmd`. Html pages produced from this file are formated `test_file.html` so I guess some transformation to a filename without spaces takes place.

I think this is a bug I should report on some bug tracker, but since I don't know whether this is about rmarkdown, knitr, pandoc, RStudio or something else I post it here.

My session info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.11

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to `rmarkdown_0.9.2` fixed the problem according to this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/580

Comment: rmarkdown 0.9 introduced the problem: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/580 and you are right that we have fixed it in 0.9.2

Comment: @YihuiXie has there been a reversion on this? Because I'm encountering the precise same issue with `{rmarkdown}` version 2.17.

Comment: It'll be nearly impossible to help without a reproducible example. Please feel free to file a Github issue with a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!